# jQuery: append to bottom, after sibling

Tags: jquery, performance

Is there a more efficient way than as follows, to append to the bottom of the same level of an element, without selecting the parent item first. Here is an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/8cEjw/

If I have the following structure:

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#main')
    .parent()
        .append($('<a>Test 1</a>').on('click', function (e) {
            alert('Test 1')
        }))
        .append($('<a>Test 2</a>').on('click', function (e) {
            alert('Test 2')
        }));
```

Then I wondered whether there is a jQuery equivalent for 'appendToBottomAfterSibling'? If I do not have .parent(), and my .append()s become .after()s, then they display in reverse order; since presumably .after() will append the element immediately after itself.

Comment: This is a little tricky to follow... It sounds like you're asking for the results of simply removing `.parent()` from your script. As in: http://jsfiddle.net/8cEjw/1/

Comment: My mistake, not quite, because I do not want to add it *in* the #main div, but I would like to add 'Test 1' and 'Test 2' *after* the main div, but in that order.

.append() was adding the new elements immediately after #main and so Test 2 appeared first (because of the nature of after). So I wondered whether there was a similar function to .after() which added it to the bottom.

Comment: I would say your code is fine to be honest. At most you could just add some specificity like this `$('#main').parent('div').append()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** As per the [JSPerf results](http://jsperf.com/test-jquery-siblings), the below is 2 orders of magnitude *slower* than the OP.

---

You could use [.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), as in `.siblings().last()`, and then [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).  (I'm not sure that is more efficient though).

```
$('#main').siblings().last().after(
    $("<a>Test1</a>") ...
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/fDL4j/1/)

(Note, if there's a chance that "#main" is the only sibling, then you can use [`.addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to include it in the selector: `$('#main').siblings().last().addBack()` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDL4j/2/))

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to benchmark to determine, or does it not usually matter if you're not doing too many operations?

Comment: @keldar it seems yours is *a lot* faster than mine (by almost 2 orders of magnitude):  http://jsperf.com/test-jquery-siblings

Comment: +1 for the effort in presenting an alternative and then also running performance on it to show original was better.